# Phonegap Android: saved picture is shown as cache group

Tags: android, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, android-gallery

I used Phonegap and the image-resizer plugin to save images into the Android device with this code:

```
try {
  // Obligatory Parameters, throw JSONException if not found
  String filename = params.getString("filename");
  filename = (filename.contains(".")) ? filename : filename + "."+ format;
  String directory = params.getString("directory");
  directory = directory.startsWith("/") ? directory : "/"+ directory;
  int quality = params.getInt("quality");
  OutputStream outStream;
  //store the file locally using the external storage directory
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .toString() + directory, filename);
  try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    if (format.equals(FORMAT_PNG)) {
      bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outStream);
    } else {
      bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outStream);
    }
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
    JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
    res.put("url", "file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, res);
    scanPhoto(imageData.substring(8));
  } catch (IOException e) {
      result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
  }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Then for it to be available in the gallery this function is called:

```
private void scanPhoto(String imageFileName) {
  Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
  File f = new File(imageFileName);
  Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
  mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
  this.cordova.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Update :However when I go to the gallery the images are in a group called **cache** so I have 2 groups camera and cache. How do I change this into the application's name instead? - got a app name now after poiting directory in a folder with my app name